# How can I tweak this validation function to work for all forms with required fields?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a working function that will check an email address and if it's correctly typed, remove the disabled attribute on the submit button.  I want to use this for all five forms on the site but it's not working when I simply use a general class that they all share.

I'm assuming I have to use `$(this)` but I can't seem to get it working.  I can duplicate this section of code four more times to cover all of the forms, but obviously, there is a better way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#headerForm input[required]').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
    $('#headerForm input[required]').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val().length == 0 || !$(this).val().match(/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/)) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#headerForm input[type="submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#headerForm input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
});
```

This is the working code. I'd like to get rid of the specific id `#headerForm` and instead just use this function on **keyup** of any input that has the required attribute.  Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mikeoberdick/pen/ZEzeBWY) that demonstrates my issue.

Comment: I am happy you got the answer on your own :-)  Answer removed

Answer (score 0):

A little sleep always seems to clarify things in the morning.  I ended up figuring out how to use $(this) correctly here in order to target each submit button based on the input being completed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.mc-field-group input[required]').keyup(function() {
    //alert('keyup');
    var empty = false;
    $typedVal = $(this).val();
    //alert($typedVal);
    if ( $typedVal.length == 0 || !$typedVal.match(/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/)) {
       empty = true;
    }

    //alert(empty);

    if (empty) {
      $(this).closest('form').find(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('form').find(':submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
});
```